# How to convert a result set in DB into merge statements in Java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have 2 schemas.

I want to first execute the select query in my source schema then convert the resultset into merge statements and merge it into destination schema.

Is it possible?

The reason not going for insert is due to a possibility of record already existing in the destination schema which would throw unique constraint while inserting.

Adding one more point: Source and destination databases reside on different servers.

Comment: Iterate over the ResultSet and add to a batch, then execute the batch every 1,000 (whatever record count makes sense) iterations.  But is java needed for this?  For example:  `merge into schema1.some_table using (select * from schema2.some_other_table` could probably be done directly within the database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tag it with the DBMS you are using. Also specify whether the source and destination databases reside in the same server/instance.

Comment: @AndrewS both the databases are on different servers but have same Schema. How do I handle in this case?

Comment: As @GordThompson suggested you should tag which database is used.  For example in Oracle create a database link to allow the merge query to be executed directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

Not sure why you think that it won't be possible. Any specific reasons ?

I am answering since you have tagged it with **jdbc** which means that you are looking for a DB agnostic solution and purely in Java.

**Merge means - update row if row already exists at target database otherwise insert new row at target database ( search criteria being primary key ) .**

So run your select on source database , iterate over it and in iteration loop ,

1. run a select on target database for primary key columns in `WHERE` clause
2. If a result is found in target db - create an `UPDATE` `PreparedStatement`  , set values in update prepared statement from source data and add to batch ( i.e. don't execute it )
3. if no row is found in step # 2 , create an `INSERT` `PreparedStatement` , set values in prepared statement from source data and add to batch
4. If batch threshold is reached, execute batches prepared at steps 2 & 3 .
5. Go to step # 1 .

Alternatively, you can try inserting individual rows & if constraint violation is thrown , try updating that row in catch block. With this approach, insert & batch statements can't be executed in batches as mentioned above.

Third approach would be to directly using MERGE statement ( if target DB supports it ) as illustrated [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/java_jdbc/s-TbMerge-java.html) , look at method - `public static void MergeTables(Connection conn)`. MERGE can be executed with jdbc statements , `executeUpdate` method.

Note that only concern for above steps is a performance concern for running step # 1 in a loop - there might be too many DB calls for large volume of data. So this kind of work is usually done in specialized ETL tools ( Informatica etc ) or PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If using a third party product is an option to you, then [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) could handle this problem pretty easily via its [export](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/) and [import](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/) capabilities. You can use any intermediary data format for this, including CSV, JSON, XML, in-memory data structures. For example, with CSV:

```java
String csv = ctx.selectFrom(SOURCE_TABLE).fetch().formatCSV();

ctx.loadInto(TARGET_TABLE)
   .onDuplicateKeyUpdate() // This produces MERGE statements
   .loadCSV(csv)
   .fields(TARGET_TABLE.fields())
   .execute();
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ